# Accessing a full object through a relation in Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am attempting to model study resources (books, DVDs, etc) and what
prerequisites those resources have.

A prerequisite is a resource also. So my question is, what Django
modelling technique best captures this relation? The study resource is
straightforward:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Resource(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    img = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField('Link to Resource', null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

However, I am not sure what the "best" way to model the
prerequisite, given that it is a `Resource` also and most importantly that **there are a variable number of prequisites** (thus eliminating the possibility of simply having a self-referential parent ). Here is my current approach:

```
class Prereq(models.Model):
    prereq = models.ForeignKey(Resource, null=True, related_name='prereq_backlink')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, null=True, related_name='prereq_resource')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.resource.title
```

The problem with this approach is that accessing a prerequisite does
not give me a full resource object to work with, so I cannot access
its various fields (title, shortcode, etc):

```
schemelab@schemelab2:~/domains/org/metaperl/tmp/idhhb/django/mysite$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from idhhb.models import Resource, Prereq
from idhhb.models import Resource, Prereq
>>> p = Resource.objects.get(id=2)
>>> p.title
u'American Book of the Dead'
>>> r = Resource.objects.get(id=2)
r = Resource.objects.get(id=2)
>>> p1 = r.prereq_backlink
>>> p2 = r.prereq_resource
>>> p1
<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x2e279d0>
>>> p2
<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x2e27a90>
>>> p1.title
p1.title
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'title'

>>> p2.title
p2.title
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'title'
>>>
```

Comment: Why not just use a self-referential relationship? If a Resource has a "parent" fk, that is your pre-requisite

Comment: Because the number of prerequisites is variable, ideally limited at 5, but that requirement can be relaxed. But there certainly isnt just one prerequisite.

Comment: OK, so why not a self referential many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this blog post](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/) I was able to implement this using `ManyToManyField` as suggested. I must say this blog post is better than any docs I found on the Django site itself.

MODEL:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    img = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField('Link to Resource', null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    prereqs = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', through='Prereq', symmetrical=False, related_name='prerequired')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Prereq(models.Model):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, null=True, related_name='main_resource')
    prereq = models.ForeignKey(Resource, null=True, related_name='prereq_resource')
```

ADMIN:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from idhhb.models import Resource, Prereq

class PrereqInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Prereq
    fk_name = 'resource'
    extra = 5

class ResourceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': 'title shortcode img summary url pub_date'.split() }),
    ]
    inlines = [PrereqInline,]


admin.site.register(Resource, ResourceAdmin)
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{% for prereq in resource.prereqs.all %}
    <li>{{ prereq.id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working the way you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`prereq_backlink` and `prereq_resource` are managers so access to the `Resource` will look like:

```
r = Resource.objects.get(id=2)
for prereq in r.prereq_backlink.all():
    print prereq.resource.title
```

But I join to @daniel-roseman's question: why you didn't use the `ManyToManyField` for this task?

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    ...
    prereqs = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

Comment: But isnt `prereq.resource.title` giving you the title of the resource with id == 2 instead of the title of the prerequisite resource?

Comment: I attempted to using `ManyToManyField` but it did not occur to me to make it self-referential. I will research the self-referential aspect now.

Comment: No, `prereq_backlink` relation is associated with the `prereq` field so it is the `prereq.prereq.title` will give you the original resource with id == 2.